# Не работает Ubuntu на VirtualBox

Tags: ubuntu, git, docker, virtualbox

С недавнего времени перестала работать Ubuntu. Подозреваю, что это связанно с тем, что я установил Git и Docker. Думаю что проблема в этом. Скачивал [здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/wsl/install-win10#step-4---download-the-linux-kernel-update-package.blob.core.windows.net/wslblob/wsl_update_x64.msi).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а можно хоть чуточку больше деталей? а то в ссылке - wsl,  в тегах virtualbox.

Comment: «вчера я отравился, подозреваю, что связано это с тем, что я ел печенюшки. думаю, проблема в них. также я пил палёную водку, купленную в подворотне».

Comment: Добавил, что показывает vbox, но не могу ничего ввести чтобы исправить kernel